# Dynamic Loading of JS and CSS using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Consider following code where I try load jquery-ui only when a popup is needed. This code will be invoked when user click on a link

```
 $.when( $.ajax({url: "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css",  dataType: "html", cache: true}), 
    $.ajax({url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js", dataType: "script", cache: true}),
    $.ajax({url: "../../plugins/jquery.dialogextend.js", dataType: "html", cache: true}) )
    .then( 
    function() { ...code for dialog goes here
```

This code fails because jquery-ui.css will not load due to same origin policy. error message is " The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS"

Now I am confused and trying to find out answer to the below two questions

1. In this code, jquery-ui.min.js is loaded but jquery-ui.css is not loaded. Due to same origin policy, if jquery-ui.css is not loaded, how jquery-ui.min.js is loaded?
2. When we include jquery-ui.css in the headed, as `<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"` 
   it will load. Why same origin policy is not applicable here

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, updated

See [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

> Here are some examples of resources which may be embedded
>   cross-origin:
>
> - JavaScript with `<script src="..."></script>`. Error messages for syntax errors are only available for same-origin scripts.
> - CSS with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`. Due to the relaxed syntax rules of CSS, cross-origin CSS requires a correct Content-Type
>     header. Restrictions vary by browser: IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
>     (scroll down to CVE-2010-0051) and Opera.

Note, `dataType` at `$.ajax()` request for `"http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"` appear to be `html` ?

Try

```
$.when( $("head").append("<link rel=stylesheet href=http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css />")
  , $.ajax({url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js", dataType: "script", cache: true})
  , $.ajax({url: "../../plugins/jquery.dialogextend.js", dataType: "html", cache: true}) )
    .then( 
    function() { ...code for dialog goes here
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but, how same origin policy works differently with this?